# Probability that the $n$-th order statistic is greater than the $50$-th percentile.

Tags: probability

Is my answer correct? I don't understand the relevance of being given the density.

**Question**

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_5$ are independently drawn from the following density
$$f_X(x) = 4.5x, \quad 0 < x < .67$$

Find the probability that the largest of the $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_5$ is greater than the $50$th percentile of this distribution.

**My Answer**

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(X_{(n)} > y) &= 1 - P(X_{(n)} \leq y), \quad \text{where $y$ is the $50$th percentile} \\
&= 1 - P(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_5 \leq y) \\
&= 1 - (F(y))^5  \quad \text{by independence} \\
&= 1 - \big (\frac{1}{2}\big )^5 \\
&= \frac{31}{32}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: It seems that the upper bound is $\frac23$ (exact value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct.

The fact that the distribution is continuous is what is relevant here.  Actually, not all definitions of percentile are the same,
but generally the $50$'th percentile of the distribution of $X$ would be a value $v$ such that
$\mathbb P(X < v) \le 1/2$ and $\mathbb P(X > v) \le 1/2$.  If the distribution is continuous, $\mathbb P(X=v) = 0$ so that implies $\mathbb P(X \le v) = 1/2$.  But if the distribution is discrete, all you can say is that $1/2 \le \mathbb P(X \le v) \le 1$.

For example, consider a discrete random variable $X$ with $\mathbb P(X=0) = 1/3$ and $\mathbb P(X = 1) = 2/3$.  Then the $50$'th percentile is $1$, and $\mathbb P(X \le 1) = 1$.